# python image unable to load using google colab environment FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, errno, filenotfounderror

I try to load python image in google colab environment. But it's failed due to

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/img.jpg'

I already uploaded image into google drive. how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow - it has been a long time. As a refresher, please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code or errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the relevant code as [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text. Show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting it like code. We [will not transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) images for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to past the exact file location:

```py
image = img.imread("D:\\Something\Something\img.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
Step one : mount google drive to colab project as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XABLW.png)

Step two:
copy image path to relevant location. see below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po82F.png)

Problem solved

Comment: The same advice for images applies to answers. If there is something you need to highlight in the Google Colab UI, then that can use an image, but also use text to explain what to do - don't just circle a button; say to click there, and explain what will happen next. If you need to talk about a change to the code, show the changed code.